# Where is the source code for electron (atom-shell) Module.require?

Tags: node.js, electron

I am using a **custom require** function which mimics [nodejs require](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/module.js#L275) and it works fine.

However, in **electron**, I get

```
SecurityError: An attempt was made to break through the security policy of the user agent.
```

when calling `window.addEventListener` inside the custom-required code.

If I could read the source code for electron's 'require' function, I could probably understand why my version fails.

Comment: I used toString() on some functions to discover the difference. The only change is related to Module._contextload strip out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for should be on GitHub.

https://github.com/atom/atom
or...
https://github.com/atom/electron
or...
https://github.com/atom/node

Based on your update the code you are looking for (with regard to sharing the global context) is actually here: https://github.com/atom/node/blob/atom-iojs/lib/module.js#L399

Because Electron doesn't include the most current version of Node.js, I thought it worth mentioning.

Comment: Actually, no. Module is not in atom/electron sources.

Comment: Np. Thanks for the solution! I'm still not sure I understand why the addEventListener triggered what looks like a sandbox context. Was that the actual source of the error, or can you say what it was?

Comment: Nm... looked up XSS. I get now how an unexpected context triggered the error.

Answer (score 1):

After inspection with `toString`, the sources are the same as nodejs except for compilation when `Module._contextload` is true. This part seems to be optimised away.

My code now works correctly by using compilation [sharing the global context](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/module.js#L443) and thus behaving as coming from the same origin (XSS prevention in chromium). This is the same functionality as `require` in electron.